# Is it possible to make an installer for a published tool, to install the tool to someone else's ArcGIS server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, installation, geoprocessing-service

I have a geoprocessing tool that works on my instance of ArcGIS for server. Is there a way to easily install this on someone else's Server, without having them run the tool and publish it through ArcGIS desktop?

For instance, I know my code is in: C:\arcgisserver\directories\arcgissystem\arcgisinput\ServiceToolbox...

Obviously I can't just copy this directory structure over to another server, and expect it to recognize it and work. But that's basically what I want to do.

Comment: You can publish a service to any ArcGIS Server instance as long as you have admin/publishing credentials and access to the server itself. Do you have access to ArcGIS Desktop, the ArcGIS Server credentials, and access to the server via the internet?

Comment: No. The server is secure and not connected to the Internet. I don't have access to the server myself.

Comment: If you can't talk to the server locally or via the internet you can't copy data to it, let alone publish a service.

Comment: Someone can take a usb stick with an install program to the computer.

Comment: Have you seen service definition files? It includes everything needed to start the service. You supply them the single file and they publish it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what I have done many times. You can author a tool, run it in ArcMap to get a result, you publish this result on an ArcGIS Server instance. Now you have a geoprocessing service (GP) there.

If you want to publish this on another machine, there are some alternatives:

1. You need to copy the Result object into another machine with ArcGIS Desktop installed that can access ArcGIS Server and you publish the Result object as a GP service.
2. You create a [`gpsddraft`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/creategpsddraft.htm) object which is essentially a zip file with all the parameters and metadata including the Result object that is used to publish the GP service. You don't need to have ArcMap on your machine, as the publishing can happen via the ArcGIS Server Manager or you can also automate it via arcpy. Look for the samples on the Help page for [`gpsddraft`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/creategpsddraft.htm). You could just a create a .py file to run when you have your draft file and py file on the usb drive.